# Get only strings from binary file

Tags: c#, xaml, label

I try to print to screen a string from a binary file using xaml labels, but when i display the file content I got a beautiful "corrupted" character instead of the entire file content.

I think the problem is reading the file, I already can change the label content using the most basic technique it work pretty well till today....

```
label.Text = mystring ;
```

The fact is : I have data in my binaries files that inst text (some random data that I don't care) located to the start of the file, my theory is my program start reading, read a non ascii character and stop reading...
I read using the File class, maybe the wrong thing.....

```
label.Text = File.ReadAllText(my_file);
```

So, im lock now. I don't exactly know what im supposed to do....

Hope you can help me :D

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much without looking at the text, but it seems you need to add the Encoding

Something like this:

```
string myText = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how your binary file is structured. You need to know the encoding of the strings. A normal text file normally has markers at the beginning two or so bytes that identify its encoding if it is Unicode. This way the system can know whether its UTF-8, UTF-16, ... 
If you try to read a binary file this Information is not there. Instead the reading process will most probably find unexpected binary data. So you cannot read a binary file as text. If your file is structured the way that at the beginning is binary data and later only text, just skip the first part and start reading at  the start of the second part. But I don't think, that it is that easy:

- if it really is binary data, chances are that the file structure is much more complicated and you need to do more work to read it.
- if only the first two bytes are binary data, then maybe its a text file and you can read it without problems, you maybe only need to pass the right encoding to the reading function